# MS Word: How to disable spell/grammar checking on a custom style

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, styles

I often write documents that contain code snippets in them. I created a custom `code` style so I can quickly differentiate words or paragraphs that are code.

However, C++ code is not easy on Word's spell checker. How do I disable the spell checker from marking all my `funnyVariableNames` as misspelled?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. Right click on the style in the Quick Style Gallery
2. Click on Modify
3. In the bottom left corner of the popup click on the Format menu
4. Click on Language
5. Select the check box "Do not check spelling or grammar" (be sure to select a language first!)
6. Click OK on the Language dialog box
7. Click OK on the Modify Style dialog box

The spell checking will not immediately disappear. But new words you create in that style will not be checked. Restarting Word works too.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work (at least not in 2003 and 2007). Applying such a style to an existing paragraph *will* perform spell checking. Haven't found a way to work around that yet...

Comment: It does work with character style however, but make sure to select a language before checking "Do not check spelling or grammar" or it won't be taken into account. It's easy to verify that by looking at the style specs, look for a "Do not check spelling or grammar, English (United Kingdom)" (the language doesn't matter of course).

Comment: I can confirm that in O365 (v2101) applying this to an existing paragraph did not remove existing spellcheck marks. However, upon reloading the document they were gone, and no new ones appeared.