# How can I get Word to omit words styled in a custom style when checking spelling?

Tags: microsoft-word

Much of my 300 page document consists of foreign language words which have been styled in one of several custom styles. I would like to omit all of the foreign words from spell check, but checking the "Do not check spelling or grammar" box (Styles > Modify Style > Language) doesn't stick. When I check the box, click OK, and open Language again the box always reverts to a partially-checked state. I don't understand what this means. By partially-checked I mean the box has a flat line in it [–] instead of a check-mark. This is not the same as completely un-checked.

The partially-checked option doesn't appear to do anything as spell check still prompts me at each of the foreign words. This is extremely frustrating as there are thousands of these words and fragments.

I'm using Word 2011 for Mac.

Comment: I'm afraid I am not experiencing the same. The check mark retains for me. I am using Word 2013 for Windows.

Comment: You might want to ask directly from Microsoft. [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011-macword?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=Threads&status=&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=All&tm=1387508145730)

Comment: Does this question help? http://superuser.com/questions/487000/ms-word-how-to-disable-spell-grammar-checking-on-a-custom-style?rq=1 See especially the last comment.